# Crossing / Knocking at/on door

Tags: word-choice, verbs, word-usage

Context: I have received a feedback request for an interview process. The company didn't offer me the job, but I appreciate their approach in requesting feedback, so I am inclined to provide it. However, I'm not sure it's anonymous and I'd like to express some criticism, but  I also would like to not be excluded from a possible recruiting process in the future because of my opinions. I told someone the following sentence:

> I am reluctant to express negative feedback to someone whose door I might knock on again in the future.

They (native speaker) corrected me saying:

> ... whose door I might cross ...

Which version do you prefer?

Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the original.

Comment: @KillingTime thanks!

Comment: Note that "crossing ones doorstep" is a somewhat archaic idiom with roughly  the same meaning as "cross paths".

Comment: @HotLicks interesting, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“On whose door I might knock” is correct. It is better not to end with a preposition.

Native speakers don’t cross a door, at least in my neck of the woods, unless they want to give the door a special blessing.

Comment: thanks a lot! FYI I can't upvote your answer, I got this msg: Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: @Tamaz I will do it for you. RealYZ is correct, as are other comments.

Comment: @Anton thank you! :)